# 16.04 install yuview issue

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ppa

I had install YUView before on this computer with same Ubuntu **16.04** Xenial. But after some problem done and a loop boot, I was forced to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 and lost applications installed. YUView is a part of them.

Now, I want to reinstall it (YUView is a software which can display `.yuv` file like `.png`, and without any issue about yuv format - 420, 422, ...), and I try to reinstall it by using same steps I use previously.

Problem : the PPA had changed (`http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt571-trusty/ubuntu`), and the repertory `Release` didn't exist anymore for `xenial`. Anyone know how I can reinstall YUView ?

NB : step for install YUView (from their [Github](https://github.com/IENT/YUView/wiki/Compile-YUView)) :

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt571-trusty -y`
- `sudo apt-get update -qq`
- `sudo apt-get install -qq qt57base; source /opt/qt57/bin/qt57-env.sh`

Edit :

```
$ sudo apt update -qq
E: The repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt571-trusty/ubuntu xenial Release  does not have a release file.
```

Comment: These steps are only needed for Ubuntu 14.04, because there are no Qt5 packages. As the README.md on the github page says use `apt-get install qt5base` to get Qt5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Download Qt 5** :

https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5

**Install Qt 5** :

```
chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run
sudo ./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run
```

Qt5 installion software will start.

Select option that you want to install (default installation is suffisant, we didn't need to add others packages, we don't try to code a program with Qt).

NB: I add the `sudo` because you can have an issue with mirror host with an error like

```
Network error while downloading 'http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/qt.io/online/qtsdkrepository/linux_x64/desktop/licenses/qt.license.gplv3except/1.0.0-1meta.7z' : Mirror host is unreachable.
```

**Install YUView**

Download the [source code from Github](https://github.com/IENT/YUView), but there is the version 2.0 [here](https://github.com/IENT/YUView/releases) (I don't use it, the 1st link is enough for me)

Extract your ZIP folder, you will get a folder named `YUView`; open a terminal inside, and use the following command  :

```
qmake
make
sudo make install
```

YUView is now installed, you can now display your favorite YUV file and some format can be read (420, 422, 444 ...)

[image]

**NB**: YUView didn't detect the size of your picture, you must **filled** `width` and `height` option like I do (my picture is from a fisheye camera, 1536 x 1536)